# RESVN SUSPENDED status for indian train

Tags: india, irctc

I am looking at train LTT HUBBALLI EXP(17322). I has RESVN SUSPENDED status from Sep, 30. I have googled and found:

> “RSVN suspended” means that the booking of seat in a particular train has been stopped due to its cancellation. There might be various reasons for cancellation like foggy weather, poor patronage, change in route etc.

But the IRCTC site allows me to buy ticket to this train right now on the dates with RESVN SUSPENDED. Why ? Cancellation is the final decision or the train will go if the tickets will be sold ?

Comment: If IRCTC allows you to buy tickets where do you see the RSVN suspended status?

Comment: @RedBaron, in the IRCTC. I have uploaded the screenshot https://pasteboard.co/ImGITDt.png. RESERV SUSPEND and `Book Now` button in the same time. I have tried to press it and it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like the given train (and its sister train in other direction) will not be run after 30 sep 2019. Per [this news item](https://www.financialexpress.com/infrastructure/railways/indian-railways-revises-time-table-for-several-central-railway-trains-with-effect-from-today-full-list-here/1624209/)

> Train number 17321 Hubballi-LTT Express cancelled with effect from 5 October 2019
>
> Train number 17322 LTT-Hubballi Express cancelled with effect from 6 October 2019

So irrespective of whether the site allows you to book ticket or not, you should look for alternate trains because this one will no longer be operating on days you wish to journey.

`RSVN suspended` does mean that reservations are no longer made for this train. Why IRCTC provides a Book Ticket option may be down to UI but I think it will not process your payment and fail the transaction if you book the ticket.